# React Native Expo: Component Exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

This is my App.js

```
import { PodcastScreen } from "./Podcast";
import { VideoScreen } from "./Video";
import { TravelScreen } from "./Travel";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Video') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-information-circle' : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Podcast') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
            } else if (route.name === 'Travel') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'tomato',
          inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Video" component={VideoScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Podcast" component={PodcastScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Travel" getComponent={TravelScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This is how Video, Podcast and Travel.js are looking

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


function Info() {

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Info</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I want to use the code form the file but current I'm getting 'Component Exception' error. If I move the code from Travel.js to App.js the problem goes away, but then the code in one file will be too big.

Is the a way in which I could access my from Travel.js in App.js

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show us the export statement in one of the files ?

Comment: I don't think so that I have that, I have add the full code of the file

Comment: you should export the Travel component something like export function TravelScreen () =>{}

Comment: export function Travel(), I changed it to this but still I have the same error. With export function Travel() => {} I get an error.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: It working, my importing of the function was also wrong. Thanks for the help